# folders and files permissions please help

Tags: permissions

Now I have 3 users: x,y,z

and 3 folders a,b,c

I want to make user x have a full permission in the 3 folders and their containing files.

I want to make user y have write+read+execute permissions on b folder and its contents only

I want to make user z to have write+read+execute permission on c folder and its contents only

How I can do it?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: no I want to manage my small business shared network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this we need to assume that `x` is member of group `g` and neither `y` nor `z` are member of that same group. Then we can set the (group) ownership and access permissions as follows:

```
chown -R x a
chown -R y:g b
chown -R z:g c

chmod -R u+rwX,go-rwx a
chmod -R ug+rwX,o-rwx b c
```

This removes the read and traversal permissions for all other users (aside from `x`, `y`, and `z`) on all three directories as well.